# Copy a template file from a modules source

Tags: python

Im writing an app that is going to be deployed as a python module.  My problem is, to use it involves a very complex configuration file in the folder you are using the application from.  I am writing a routine that checks to see if the file exists in the current folder, but im having trouble copying the default configuration file over.

so basically, I want to be able to copy the file located in

```
/usr/lib/python2-7/dist-packages/myapp/default.ini
```

to the current folder.  How would I access the path to this file on win,osx,and nix systems?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're using `setuptools` (or `distribute`… but if that's the case, you should update to `setuptools`), the [documentation](https://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/setuptools.html#including-data-files) explains this. (Make sure to read the following two sections as well.)

First, a normal setuptools install will put your files somewhere under /usr/local/share or the like, not inside your package.

You can override this, but if you do, that means they may end up inside a myapp.egg file, or a site-packages.zip, or even built into a .exe. In any of those cases, you can't access them by path at all.

The easy solution to all of these problems is to use [`pkg_resources`](http://peak.telecommunity.com/DevCenter/PythonEggs#accessing-package-resources). Then, your code doesn't have to know anything about eggs or zipfiles or whatever, you just open the resource by name.

Of course this means you can't just `shutil.copy(datapath, './default.ini')`; you'll have to do `with open('./default.ini', 'w') as f: f.write(datacontents)`. But that's about the only real added complexity.

Comment: im trying this, and its working in ubuntu `templatePath = path.join(os.path.dirname(myapp.__file__ ), "config/template.myapp.flowini")`, if im reading you right, on other os's, packages are deployed in glorified zip files, not expanded folders like linux, is that right?

Comment: oh, i think i see what your doing now.  instead of copying a file, your writing a new file using contents of a package resource.  ok, i will start playing with this and see how it goes.   thanks

Comment: @scphantm: Exactly. That's all a file copy ends up doing anyway (well, that, and possibly settings permissions and other attributes, and checking to make sure you aren't copying a file to itself, and so on). See the source to [shutil.py](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/shutil.py) for exact details on how each function works, but ultimately, it all comes down to `copyfileobj`, which just `read`s the source file and `write`s the dest file. So, if you get the source file's contents in some other way, just `write` the dest file.

Comment: Is this better than [`pkgutil.get_data`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/pkgutil.html#pkgutil.get_data)?

Answer (score 0):

Within a Python module, the `__file__` variable holds the full path to the file of that module. So, from within a `myapp.something` module (thus, `.../myapp/something.py`), you can write:

```
import os
os.path.abspath(os.path.join(__file__, '..', 'default.ini'))
```

Comment: This doesn't work if the package gets installed as an egg. It also doesn't work if someone uses your module to build a py2app/py2exe/pyinstaller/etc. package that bundles up a site-packages.zip or similar. So, this is a bad idea for something you plan to distribute as a package.